# igraph dendogram not arranging vertices by cluster

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, igraph

I am running cluster analysis in R using igraph, both plotting the results against a network graph and using a dendogram. Most of the time the two line up, but for one set of data the dendogram is shading vertices by their cluster but not putting them next to each other. They're actually almost in alphabetical order. I can't tell if this is some quirk of presentation, or if it indicates an issue with the clustering. I'm not able to share my data, but below is the general code I'm using.

```
 s <- graph.data.frame(s_edges, vertices = nodes_use, directed=FALSE)
 sc <- leading.eigenvector.community(s)
 V(s)$community <- membership(sc)
 s_sub1 <- delete_vertices(s, V(s)[community != 1])
 sc1 <- leading.eigenvector.community(s_sub1)
 plot(s_sub1, mark.groups = communities(sc1), layout = layout_with_lgl)
 dendPlot(sc1)
```

Comment: The dendrogram you see in the plot is invalid. Please do not use it. The grouping you get is fine though.  Bug report was filed here: https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues/797